# Keyword-Search with synonyms in information retrieval systems

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval, nlp

I have development a chatbot to give right answer for user input. Right now, I struggle how to read the DB/Knowledge Base or just the json file properly to extract the right answer. In my use case I have very much Keyword names/entities together with synonyms. So it would be a bad idea to write the synonyms in the NLU training file manually. My database file has first listed the keyword and afterwards the answers are separated for each intent belonging to this entity. How do you handle in practice such keyword search together with slightly different keywords/synonyms given by the user?

I am interested in standard approach to this and in future I would like to apply NLP maybe like word emebedding for my custom case.

Comment: The phrasing of your question is very poor. Please take more time to write a question that everybody can understand.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.